# Convert a string of ndarray to ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have a string of ndarray. I want to convert it back to ndarray.
I tried  `newval = np.fromstring(val, dtype=float)`. But it gives `ValueError: string size must be a multiple of element size`

Also I tried `newval = ast.literal_eval(val)`. This gives

```
File "<unknown>", line 1
[-1.45181984e-01  1.51671678e-01  1.59053639e-01 -1.02861412e-01
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

> String of ndarray

```
 '[-1.45181984e-01  1.51671678e-01  1.59053639e-01 -1.02861412e-01
 -9.70948339e-02 -1.75551832e-01 -7.24434480e-02  1.19182713e-01
 -4.54084426e-02 -9.23779532e-02  8.87222588e-02  1.05331177e-02
 -1.31792471e-01  3.50326337e-02 -6.58577830e-02  1.02670217e+00
 -5.29987812e-02  2.09167395e-02 -1.19845152e-01  2.30511073e-02
  2.89404951e-02  4.17387672e-02 -2.08203331e-01  2.34342851e-02]'
```

How can I convert this back to ndarray?

Comment: Honestly, by not having something like that in the first place. (You're already losing information since numbers are being rounded there.) Please serialize your arrays into a machine-readable format instead of trying to go through a string meant for human consumption.

Comment: Is keeping this in byte format fine?

Comment: If you're saving to disk to solely use the data with NumPy, use https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html and `numpy.load`.

Comment: I am storing these arrays in LevelDB as key value pairs. The arrays are fasttext vectors. In levelDB vector (value) for each ngram (key) are stored. Is what you mentioned above applicable here?

Comment: Yes. You'd use something like `bio = io.BytesIO(); np.save(bio, my_array); ldb.put('my-key', bio.getvalue())` to save and `bio = io.BytesIO(ldb.get('my-key')); arr = np.load(bio);` to load.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To expand upon my comment:

If you're trying to parse a human-readable string representation of a NumPy array you've acquired from somewhere, you're already doing something you shouldn't.

Instead use [`numpy.save()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) and [`numpy.load()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.load.html#numpy.load) to persist NumPy arrays in an efficient binary format.

Maybe use `.savetxt()` if you need human readability at the expense of precision and processing speed... but never consider `str(arr)` to be something you can ever parse again.

However, to answer your question, if you're absolutely desperate and don't have a way to get the array into a better format...

```py
>>> data = '''
... [-1.45181984e-01  1.51671678e-01  1.59053639e-01 -1.02861412e-01
...  -9.70948339e-02 -1.75551832e-01 -7.24434480e-02  1.19182713e-01
...  -4.54084426e-02 -9.23779532e-02  8.87222588e-02  1.05331177e-02
...  -1.31792471e-01  3.50326337e-02 -6.58577830e-02  1.02670217e+00
...  -5.29987812e-02  2.09167395e-02 -1.19845152e-01  2.30511073e-02
...   2.89404951e-02  4.17387672e-02 -2.08203331e-01  2.34342851e-02]
... '''.strip()
>>> list_of_floats = [float(x) for x in data.strip('[]').split(None)]
[-0.145181984, 0.151671678, 0.159053639, -0.102861412, -0.0970948339, -0.175551832, -0.072443448, 0.119182713, -0.0454084426, -0.0923779532, 0.0887222588, 0.0105331177, -0.131792471, 0.0350326337, -0.065857783, 1.02670217, -0.0529987812, 0.0209167395, -0.119845152, 0.0230511073, 0.0289404951, 0.0417387672, -0.208203331, 0.0234342851]
```

*EDIT:* For the case OP mentioned in the comments,

> I am storing these arrays in LevelDB as key value pairs. The arrays are fasttext vectors. In levelDB vector (value) for each ngram (key) are stored. Is what you mentioned above applicable here?

Yes – you'd use [`BytesIO` from the `io` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) to emulate an in-memory "file" NumPy can write into, then put that buffer into LevelDB, and reverse the process (read from LevelDB into an empty BytesIO and pass it to NumPy) to read:

```py
bio = io.BytesIO()
np.save(bio, my_array)
ldb.put('my-key', bio.getvalue())
# ...
bio = io.BytesIO(ldb.get('my-key'))
my_array = np.load(bio)
```